# Nuget DLL location issues with SVN

Tags: c#, nuget

We have a .csproj that is being worked on by a number of people.

Unfortunately nuget has installed its 'packages' in different locations on each users machine, meaning when another user does an SVN 'update', their project wont compile because the .csproj file's 'hintpath' element is pointing to the dll in a different location.

Are there any other solutions to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NuGet [packages restore feature](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages) and don't commit packages to source control.
This allows NuGet client application to download packages on demand. Downloaded packages will be located in solution folder, so, references to packages content will work at any machines.

Comment: @maxp: we're using this feature in our team, it works well. It works even at CC .NET server.